# Problems with data driven testing in MSTest

Tags: c#, selenium, automated-tests, mstest, data-driven-tests

I am trying to get data driven testing to work in C# with MSTest/Selenium.
Here is a sample of some of my code trying to set it up:

```
[TestClass]
public class NewTest
{
    private ISelenium selenium;
    private StringBuilder verificationErrors;
    [DeploymentItem("GoogleTestData.xls")]
    [DataSource("System.Data.OleDb",
    "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=GoogleTestData.xls;Persist Security Info=False;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0'",
    "TestSearches$", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]

    [TestMethod]
    public void GoogleTest()
    { 
        selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*iehta", http://www.google.com);
        selenium.Start();
        verificationErrors = new StringBuilder();
        var searchingTerm = TestContext.DataRow["SearchingString"].ToString();
        var expectedResult = TestContext.DataRow["ExpectedTextResults"].ToString();

    ...
```

Here's my error:
Error 3 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestContext.DataRow.get' E:\Projects\SeleniumProject\SeleniumProject\MaverickTest.cs 32 33 SeleniumProject

The error is underlining the "TestContext.DataRow" part of both statements.
I've really been struggling with this one, thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure how to get the code in there without it getting butchered? sorry everyone

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try:

```
public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }
```

and try using it like:

```
this.TestContext.DataRow["SearchingString"].ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried your code additions and it is telling me it cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Data.DataRow' do you suppose that is an issue with my setup to the spreadsheet? I'm brand new to c# if you couldn't tell!

Comment: Nevermind...got it working.. you were dead on with the TestContext method thanks! This is how I had to use it to get it to work:
searchTerm = System.Convert.ToString(TestContext.DataRow["SearchingString"]);

Comment: This helped me when I was using the same csv for multiple tests in the same class. See http://geekswithblogs.net/Aligned/archive/2013/11/04/selenium-ndash-use-data-driven-tests-to-run-in-multiple.aspx for more details. Thanks!