# Data driven testing in MSTest - problem with TestContext.DataRow

Tags: c#, automated-tests, mstest, data-driven-tests

I'm having essentially the same problem as the question linked below, but I cannot seem to get it to work. I'm getting "cannot apply indexing [] to an expression of type System.Data.DataRow". As far as I can tell, I have implemented the solution correctly.

[Problems with data driven testing in MSTest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993298/problems-with-data-driven-testing-in-mstest/2993346#2993346)

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    private TestContext testContextInstance;

    public TestContext TestContext
    {
        get
        {
            return testContextInstance;
        }
        set
        {
            testContextInstance = value;
        }
    }        

    private ServiceReference1.ProductCatalogClient client = new ServiceReference1.ProductCatalogClient("BasicHttpBinding_IProductCatalog");

    [DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.CSV", "|DataDirectory|\\CountList.csv", "CountList#csv", DataAccessMethod.Sequential), DeploymentItem("..\\ServiceTest\\CountList.csv"), TestMethod]
    public void AreCountsCorrect()
    {
        int id = TestContext.DataRow["Id"] as int;
        int count = client.GetProductCount(id);
        Assert.IsTrue(count == TestContext.DataRow["Count"] as int);
    }
}
```

Comment: Found my issue: Needed to add a reference to System.Data in my test project.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add a reference to `System.Data` to the test project. No idea why that would not be automatically included since DataRow is used for data driven tests.

Answer (score 5):

You should add Reference to your test project to fix this issue. I don't know why VS2013 doesn't add it automatically.

right click your test project, Add->Reference...->Assemblies->Framework->System.Data, check it.

Done!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you with the this.TestContext.DataRow["PathFile_Original"],
what I was doing wrong was so simple, I didn't add the reference to System.Data, that was all.

It's quite easy to fix, be sure that you already have library.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

To fix your issue, as others have said, you should add a reference to `System.Data` in your project.

If you are still having an issue after that reference has been added, you may need to restart Visual Studio, and remove any redundant references or `using` headers.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Thanks Bob. I've edited my answer so that it reads as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

this one is working with me

```
[TestMethod]
    [TestCategory("Category 4")]
    [DataSource("MyExcelDataSource")]
    [DeploymentItem("UnitTestProject\\DBConnections.xlsx")]
    public void testwithexceldata()
    {
        //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcontext.datarow.aspx

        int x = TestContext.DataRow.Table.Rows.Count;
        int Balance = Convert.ToInt32(TestContext.DataRow["Balance"]);
        int Amount = Convert.ToInt32(TestContext.DataRow["Amount"]);
        Assert.AreEqual(Balance, Amount);
```

}